# Rest Template with slash in uri param

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, resttemplate, slash

i'm doing a REST call with `RestTemplate`, and I have a uriparam which contains a slash (i.e. 20/20)

Prior to calling the `RestTemplate`, I convert the uriParam to using http encoding to `20%2f20`.

When I call RestTemplate, it converts the `%` to `%25` and the data that I receive is not correct.

It's possible to call a restTemplate with slash in the param?

Thanks!

Code example:

```
String urlExample="www.nowhere.com/?variable={variable}";
String variable = URLEncoder.encode( "20/20", java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString() );

Map< String, String > uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
 uriVariables.put( "variable", variable );

restTemplate.exchange( urlExample, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>, String.class, uriVariables );
```

- If I don't do the httpEncoder I obtain a rest call to: http://www.nowhere.com/?variable=20/20, and the value variable gets is 20 only.
- If I do the httpEncoder, the value of variable is %2F (It is correct, that's the value I want) but when I do the rest call it calls to: http://www.nowhere.com/?variable=20%252F20.

It seems the RestTemplate encodes to HttpEncoding the % to %25 and it breaks my call. It's possible to avoid this encoding?

Solved:

if you indicate the restTemplate to use URI instead String, RestTemplate avoids the encoding.

For build the uri with params, best method is with UriComponentsBuilder indicating that the uri is actually encoded in the build() param.

Comment: did you try skipping http encoding altogether?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @diginoise how can I skip the httpEncoding? I thought that was a possible solution but I didn't find anything about that.

Comment: Code example in question.

Comment: Edit your question and show what you are trying to do. What the URL template like?

Answer (score 0):

Try below logic for your test handler which can be "`www.nowhere.com/a/b/c`" and you will get the whole value using following mechanism.

```
requestedUri = (String) 
request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
```

Comment: I understand your code takes the Controller url, not an url I want to encode.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure the RestTemplate as follows:

```
DefaultUriTemplateHandler uriTemplateHandler = new UriTemplateHandler();
uriTemplateHandler.setParsePath(true);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(uriTemplateHandler);
```